# Index was outside the bounds of the array with jagged array c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jagged-arrays

i want to try jagged arrays but i got an index out range exception , any help ?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[][] jaggedarr = new int[1][];


  jaggedarr[0] = new int[0];


            jaggedarr[0][0] = 25;

            Console.WriteLine(jaggedarr[0][0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define the jagged arrays as the following code without exception.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] jaggedarr = new int[1][];
            jaggedarr[0] = new int[0];
            jaggedarr[0] = new int[] { 25};
            Console.WriteLine(jaggedarr[0][0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
jaggedarr[0] = new int[0];
```

this creates a list with zero size. You want a list of size 1.

Comment: @AnaRoyal - I've tried the code in your question and modified the line suggested by JonasH to be jaggedarr[0] = new int[1]; and this compiles and displays 25 in the console.